# SO should validate a username in the URL and issue a redirect on mismatch, right?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, vanity-url

Please read: [Matt Cutts: "Adding a 301 redirect can be an especially good idea if your site changes"](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/)

If I'm johnny my URL might be 134564/johnny and if I change my username to paul, and people have outside links to my profile at 134564/johnny, they'll still work. This means more than one URL to a page. Issue a 301 if the name doesn't match (doesn't waste more DB, as you need the username in the profile anyway).

Comment: The link still works. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe we should just have '/users/134564' and call it a day.

Comment: see random's answer -- this isn't necessary because we have a canonical link tag

Comment: Wow good thing you guys closed this one because it was a really offensive question to ask. I didn't mean to offend anyones's intelligence I promise. I really like all of you guys a lot.

Answer (score 10):

You should read some of Matt Cutts' later stuff. Like the one [posted in 2009 about the canonical tag](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/):

> An ugly url such as http://www.example.com/page.html?sid=asdf314159265 can specify in the HEAD part of the document the following:
>
> ```
> <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/page.html"/>
> ```
>
> That tells search engines that the preferred location of this url (the “canonical” location, in search engine speak) is http://example.com/page.html instead of http://www.example.com/page.html?sid=asdf314159265 .

And it's already implemented in the trilogy of sites.

Comment: You were supposed to *only* read http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/ Why don't you get that? +1, and more if I could.

Comment: Canonical tags are meant for use with content that has multiple urls, not for broken systems that leave old urls around. I know it's tough to understand.

Comment: @orokusaki: no one who has replied here is a site maintainer or anything but what you are: a *user*. So your comments seem somewhat misplaced, not to mention offensive.

Comment: @orokusaki: 134564/johnny and 134564/paul *are* multiple urls for the same content, exactly what the `rel="canonical"` tag is designed to handle

Answer (score 7):

What's the benefit of issuing a redirect (causing an extra request) instead of just serving the right content?

Comment: SEO. Google doesn't like duplicated content.

Comment: There is still the canonical tag that helps search engines filter the dupe content. @kop

Comment: @random: I don't understand... What's the canonical tag? O.o

Comment: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/

Comment: @Koper: you can learn about the canonical tag here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html and here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394, among other places. (see also @random's answer)

Answer (score 4):

So should we also be redirecting the URL on questions if the title in the URL is incorrect?

[meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36723/we-love-ponies-we-love-ponies-we-love-ponies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36723/we-love-ponies-we-love-ponies-we-love-ponies)

Comment: Ideally, yes. See my comment to Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/