# Is editing someone else's question's title completely justified and proper or self serving?

Tags: discussion, edits, users, behavior

So Mr Jeff Atwood decides to completely change my [**question** title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/37818/revisions). And that was after it was changed by another person. I find this act annoying and disingenuous. I understand some people didn't like what I said and the post was voted down many times. But does every question have to be "nice"?

I too have an opinion to make. Or is this not a free area? Is every person with enough reputation here to make every post look pretty? The new title does not correctly convey my intent. The question wasn't about fonts in particular. It was about why some good questions get closed in general. [The fonts question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming-closed) was just an example.

Sometimes I feel some people don't know how to use the extra power they have. 
How would Jeff feel if I changed one of his question's title according to what I *think* should be proper?

Do you trust a post by someone when it has been edited to serve the publisher? 
I think I should just ask technical questions and stay away from politics.

Comment: Maybe you should read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Given your question and answer history, where you don't upvote other people's answers but instead post your own answer (which rarely gets upvotes) and accept that, I would judge that you don't know how to play well with others, something that this entire thread is amply demonstrating.

Comment: "How would Jeff feel..." - He'd say something like "Hey cool, my site works."  Maybe.

Comment: Is this thread not dead yet?

Comment: @dboarman: It's feeling much better now.

Answer (score 12):

Given the title on the question, changing it was totally justified. If you cannot ask your question civilly, perhaps you should not be asking it at all.  Let's all try to be adults, mmkay?

Today must be quote from the FAQ day, because this clause also applies:

### Other people can edit my stuff?!

> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your posts being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

<sub><wistful>If only we had some of the close reasons [proposed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38215/not-a-real-question-on-meta/38221#38221), the discussion would now be over.</wistful></sub>

Comment: Then change it to a more civilized version that conveys the SAME meaning and intension. That's what an editor did already and I was Ok with it. However Jeff comes along and changes it to something else.

Edits on Wikipedia are about posting facts and it's open and not based on a point and reward system.

Comment: @Tony: was your intention and meaning to be blatantly offensive? That's how a large part of the world will react when you invoke the name of one of the most horrifying regimes of the 20th century.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to your question is in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

> does every questions has to be 'nice'?

From the FAQ:

> ### Be Nice

So yes!
And as for the rest of your question, I think you need to lose the feeling of ownership of the questions you ask.  They are not yours!  Every question you ask become part of the SO community for everyone's benefit.  Yes you may get some rep points for contributing a good question or providing a good answer, but in the end the purpose of the entire site is to be a resource for programmers/sysadmins/superusers everywhere to be able to find answer to common, and not so common, questions.

Comment: -1 @heavyd. There is a difference between being nice in your behaviour to other users (which is how I read the FAQ 'Be Nice') and being nice in the subject matter of your questions. We have a serious problem if S/OFU becomes a place where only 'nice' questions are allowed and you are not allowed to ask questions of a contentious nature/subject matter. Let the voting do it's job in sorting the good from the bad.

Comment: @David: Asking hard questions is allowed even encouraged if they are reasonably objective *or* can be handled in a non-argumentative way. Calling people names is, well, discouraged.

Comment: @dmckee:  While the line between 'hard' and 'contentious' is a bit blurry, I totally agree with you on the name calling issue.  No need for that at all.

Answer (score 6):

1. Editing is one of the single best features of SOFU.
2. If you think someone who closes is a question about programming fonts is a Nazi, you don't know what a Nazi is.

Comment: The Nazi reference was about the habit of closing questions from the same people. It wasn't about that question in particular. No one scolded Seinfeld for using that reference. In fact many people thought it was funny.

Comment: @Tony, you called people names, and they treated you *nicely* by just editing the names out. It was more than you deserved, but we try to be nice. If the team has so much as waved the `PenaltyBoxMallet` (AKA `--BanHammer`) in your general direction, we don't know about it. Now is the time to move on.

Comment: Hey Jon, you killed the joke!

Answer (score 1):

Roll it Back.  That is the power you have. (and you'll get a badge if you haven't gotten it yet).

Comment: Rolling back an edit where Jeff removed an gratuitous use of "Nazis" to refer to other users is probably not the best idea I've every heard...

Comment: @dmckee: I'm sure a rollback would get this thread closed ;)

Comment: I don't have time to waste on rolling back posts when I know the same people will quickly undo my rollback. BTW,  edits on my posts on meta have happened several times before, even without offending anyone. It's a losing ground with people who spend their lives on the trilogy sites! There's always a wise guy who thinks he can say it better.

Comment: @Tony: Once again, the FAQ says it clearly: "Other people can edit my stuff!" 'Tis the nature of the sites. It's designed for people (like myself) to go in and edit posts appropriately, for grammar, spelling, punctuation, correct name usage and yes, to remove unnecessary name-calling.

Comment: @State of the union. You don't get it. I was complaining of the nature of some edits to the point where it's changes the meaning and the message. Not the fact there are edits.

Comment: @Tony: I wholeheartedly support changing the meaning when the meaning is insulting to the majority of users. The primary point of "why do questions get closed" can easily be expressed without calling such people Nazis. You can still edit the title any way you like, and I doubt anyone would change it unless it was offensive. In fact, I've done so for you, calling it "Overzealous Stack Overflow Question Closers," still holds your original intent, without offense. I even fixed a typo for you.