# Ow, it burns. My eyes!

Tags: discussion, stackapps, humor

This is just wrong.

[image: The StackApps 404 page. My eyes. The goggles do nothing.]

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/14382211817

Comment: http://stackapps.com/404

Comment: So is stackapps.com what used to be dev.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Ether - i don't know about dev.meta. StackApps is geared toward use of the rest api.

Comment: When did 'noise or pointless' get added to the close reasons? ;-)

Comment: @Ether: Yes, when the private beta ended they closed down dev.meta and opened up stackapps.com.

Comment: @code poet: May 7th. [“Not a real question” on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38215/not-a-real-question-on-meta/38681#38681)

Comment: I love the "However, we did find this totally unrelated yet humorous picture of something that doesn't help you at all" pages, they're great.  This one actually made me lol.

Comment: *What happens on http://stackapps.com, stays on http://stackapps.com.*

Comment: Well, we can't please everyone...

Comment: For those interested, [Google Image Search results for this picture](http://tinyurl.com/mp9oqqs). :D

Comment: try to not take time with such a unusable thing