# Close reasons on meta SE sites should be consistent with MSO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, per-site-meta

There are 5 close reasons in MSO:

- exact duplicate,
- off-topic
- subjective and argumentative
- too localized
- **noise or pointless**

but the **noise or pointless** reason does not exist on meta SE 2.0 sites, and "not a real question" is still there:

- exact duplicate,
- off-topic
- subjective and argumentative
- *not a real question*
- too localized

Should the close reasons on meta SE 2.0 sites align with those of MSO?

(References:

- [*“Not a real question” on Meta?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38215/not-a-real-question-on-meta) — where NaRQ is decided to be replaced by noise or pointless on MSO
- [*Meta.Meta: Please add new close reason: Noise or Pointless*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/918/meta-meta-please-add-new-close-reason-noise-or-pointless) — the original feature-request on math.SE.

)

Comment: To close vote reviewers: this question is [tag:status-completed], it doesn't *need* to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the name of consolidation and simplifying the existing standard close reasons, we're changing "subjective and argumentative" to

> **not constructive**
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

The meta "noise or pointless" will be decommissioned and folded into this one. That is, if something was closed as NoP it will (soon) be retroactively closed as "not constructive".