# Re-add "not a real question" as closing reason for meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons

Stack Exchange 2.0 sites have "not a real question" as closing reason; the only exception is this very site.

[image: screenshot taken from meta.drupal.stackexchange.com]

May this closing reason be re-added?

I have never seen feature requests, or bug reports being closed as not a real question simply for the fact they are request, or reports; if they have been closed as such is because it was difficult to tell what was being asked. I think the community on *Meta Stack Overflow* already shown to know when this closing reason should be used; the fact that in the meta sites I visit the same closing reason has never been used for feature requests should mean users know when the closing reason should be used.

Comment: Plenty of things here aren't questions, and are perfectly valid...

Comment: @NickCraver That would apply to other meta sites as well. I don't think bug reports, or feature requests would be closed as "not a real question" just for the fact they are bug reports, or feature requests; if that were to happen, they would be clearly closed for the wrong reason.

Comment: then the correct request would be to remove it from those child metas as well, would it not?  The criteria seems pretty straight-forward to me, it shouldn't be offered as a close reason *if it's not a reason to close the question*.

Comment: @NickCraver If that closing reason is removed, what other closing reason should be used? Should "not constructive" be used?

Comment: Absolutely, if someone brings a rant here on meta with no real problem, no solution and is doing something completely *not constructive*, that's a valid close reason...it gets used for precisely that reason fairly regularly.

Comment: @NickCraver I kind of miss _noise or pointless_, but it is a kinder .. gentler Meta after all.

Comment: I want to close this as not a real question. What a Catch-22.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You could also close it as off-topic; that doesn't mean it is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Not a real question* is not a closing reason in any meta site, nowadays.

> [image: meta.stackoverflow.com]

> [image: meta.stackexchange.com]

> [image: drupal.meta.stackexchange.com]

Since meta sites for Stack Exchange 2.0 sites don't have that closing reason anymore, I think it should not be introduced on Meta Stack Overflow too.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things that are valid on this site that aren't questions.

These include:

- Bug reports
- Feature requests
- Stuff that you need to bring to attention to moderators (when flagging doesn't help)
- Discussion about a topic

Comment: "saying that the question doesn't fit into any category that meta is for" That would be "off topic", no?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah. My english isn't great. Somebody can edit that to whatever they want (don't vandalise it though).

Comment: It's not an issue with language, but if something doesn't fit what meta is intended for, what else would it be if not "off topic"?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Good point. I was thinking almost the same thing when I was writing it. I was hoping someone would edit that to make it sound better. But I'll just delete it now.

Comment: If this is the argument, then "not constructive" could be applied for all the discussions, as it says, "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." I expect the community to choose the right closing reason for the right questions; differently, questions that are on-topic could be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Is discussion valid in Meta SO?

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's basically copied from SO. I believe that you are allowed discussion in MSO. There is a [meta-tag:discussion] tag for that. It should be changed.

Comment: @Anish Gupta: [Sure.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107073/is-the-not-constructive-close-reason-appropriate-for-meta

Comment: @moguzalpenel_hak I meant that bit which had something like "maybe it should be changed to [...]".

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I have read that before. What I am arguing here is the argument used in this answer.