# Stack Apps still has a "Noise or pointless" flag

Tags: bug, flags, close-reasons, stackapps

Per Jeff's (old) answer at [Close reasons on meta SE sites should be consistent with MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67393/close-reasons-on-meta-se-sites-should-be-consistent-with-mso):

> The meta "noise or pointless" will be decommissioned and folded into [not constructive]. That is, if something was closed as NoP it will (soon) be retroactivey closed as "not constructive".

However, the *Noise or pointless* flag is still visible on Stack Apps:

[image]

Comment: I asked about this yesterday and Shog said this is "expected."

Answer (score 3):

This is no longer the case as it apparently merged or is now covered by "rude/abusive".

[image]

Why there? Well, it's explained in this [FAQ answer for when each flag should be used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/278543):

> Abuse of the system or community is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts that contain no useful content at all – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
> > asyuv;laergap897wertp[98 gb;vp98a34
>
> Cats are not allowed to walk across keyboards as part of Stack Exchange posts; this is abuse and should be flagged as such.

Since nonsensical, pointless stuff is covered under this flag, I would say [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)