# Can the Description for the CloseReasonTypes be added for the newer Close Reasons?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, close-reasons

The table CloseReasonTypes in [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) holds the id, name and description for the various close reasons.

When the close reasons got [a major overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) the new close reasons got numbers > 100. For unclear reasons the Description field of those new close reasons are null, while the older ones got their description attribute filled.

[image: closereasons with missing values in dataset]
<sub>Click image for SEDE query</sub>

Can this omission of the description for this newer close reasons be rectified so that the data is consistent? I allow for a 6 to 8 weeks delivery date.

Comment: My guess is that it is related to [localization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414)...

Comment: It's not that we're excluding them, they are null because there are no descriptions in the database. I'll see if I can find out why they weren't populated.

Comment: Now I'm curious about "noise of pointless" close reason... **Edit:** oh, it's a close reason [on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67393/241919)...