# The close reason descriptions for "Needs details or clarity" and "Opinion-based" are swapped in SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, close-reasons

The close reason descriptions for "Needs details or clarity" and "Opinion-based" are swapped in SEDE. Can this be corrected?

[image: List of descriptions of close reasons with IDs 103 to 105.]

For reference, this is what those close reason descriptions look like on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) when the close dialog box is opened:

[image: Close dialog box showing the relevant close reasons and their descriptions.]

Comment: They got added as part of this request of mine: [Can the Description for the CloseReasonTypes be added for the newer Close Reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327636/can-the-description-for-the-closereasontypes-be-added-for-the-newer-close-reason) but I didn't check the result earlier.

Comment: @rene so it's your fault...typical. :P

Comment: To CVers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67393/close-reasons-on-meta-se-sites-should-be-consistent-with-mso#comment1182279_67393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the main production databases and the changes were captured in the weekly refresh of SEDE yesterday.

We missed the swap when we added the [descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327636/can-the-description-for-the-closereasontypes-be-added-for-the-newer-close-reason) earlier this year.