# Typo in old close reason 'noise or pointless' in SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, close-reasons

There used to be a close reason ['noise or pointless'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67393/295232) on Meta sites. However, in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1284628/close-reasons) it's listed as "noise o***f*** pointless", which makes it look like the person who inserted that was either [Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Conjunction_2), inebriated or possibly both.

[image]

Comment: Pointless is very nosy, didn't you know that?! :-D

Comment: Meh, it works for me ...

Comment: @rene nah, makes it sound as though it's pointless noise.

Comment: What *is* the noise of pointless?

Comment: To those who don't have English as a first language: The current "not constructive" was called "noise or pointless" (two separate choices). The SEDE version "noise of pointless" means that the "noise" is a possession of "pointless" - either the post is pointless and also contains noise ***or*** the writer is a pointless person and that is their noise. The first interpretation doesn't make sense in the context, the second is rude.

Comment: Going to look into this one - will update here with more

Comment: "Fools", said I, "You do not know,
Spammers like unicorns grow,
Upvote my posts that I might teach you,
Don't flag them that I might reach you",
But my posts, like yesterday's old joys,
Were voted as the Noise of Pointless

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done, well, partly done.

The production databases have been updated with to read `noise or pointless`, but SEDE won't get the changes until next Sunday when the weekly refresh hits.